# Issue with Using Vue.js for Image Paths with Variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, web, frontend

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to create a dynamic image path based on the props passed using Vue.js. I've tried creating variables with the images, using CSS variables, and changing the path to the public folder (which worked, but I need the images to be in the src folder for an optimization plugin). I've consulted the documentation, but I'm still facing difficulties.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'card',
    props: {
      product: String,
      text: String,
    },
    methods:{
      redirect(){
        this.$router.push(this.product)
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
    <div @click="redirect()" class="card" :style="`background-image: url(/src/assets/images/${product}/cardImg.svg)`">
        <div class="card-text d-flex flex-column gap-3">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
            <img :src="`/src/assets/images/${product}/${product}Logo.svg`" alt="Logo">
            <i class="bi bi-arrow-right"></i>
          </div>
          <p>{{text}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<style scoped>
 .card{
   max-width: 90%;
   width: 402px;
   height: 568px;
   background-size: cover;
   border-radius: 24px;
   padding: 2rem 1rem;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 .card:hover{
   scale: 105%;
 }
 img{
   filter: brightness(100);
   height: 40px;
 }
 .bi-arrow-right {
   color: #ffffff;
   scale: 200%;
 }
 p{
   color: #FFFFFF;
 }
 .card-text{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 350px;
 }
</style>
```

What did you try and what were you expecting?

I've attempted the following approaches:

1. Created variables for the images and used them in the template.
2. Used CSS variables to dynamically set image paths.
3. Changed the image path to the public folder, but this isn't optimal for an optimization plugin.

I was expecting that one of these approaches would successfully generate dynamic image paths based on the props passed to the Vue component. However, I'm still facing difficulties, and the paths are not resolving as expected. I consulted the documentation, but I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: what version of Vue?  using Webpack or Vite?

Comment: @vue/cli 5.0.8 and Vite

Comment: vue-cli is webpack.  you can't use both webpack and vite together.  you also didn't mention what version **vue** is, which will either be 2.x or 3.x version number

Comment: version vue.js 3.x

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve dynamic path Vite should be able to get paths at build time. Seems that's impossible since products are fetch dynamically. Anyway [the dynamic import is pretty limited](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#dynamic-import) (there could be another reason that it fails in your case).

[Use glob](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import):

```
methods:{
  getProductLogoUrl(product){
    // find the url in this.images
  }
},
data: {
      // i don't remember whether we need the opening slash, try it out
      images: import.meta.glob('/src/assets/images/*/*Logo.svg', { as: 'url', eager: true })
    },
...
<img :src="getProductLogoUrl(product)" alt="Logo">
```

You can bind component data with `v-bind` to CSS properties in Vue 3 also.